# Java Script. Looping stops as soon as variable == 0

Tags: javascript, loops, return

Here's my code where I'm looking for opportunities in tri-ang arbitrage.

```
// Loop through each trade and get Price information
  for (let i = 0; i < fileJsonArrayLimit.length; i++) {
    console.log(fileJsonArrayLimit.length)
    // Extract the variables
    let swap1 = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].swap1
    let pair1ContractAddress = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolContract1
    let pair2ContractAddress = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolContract2
    let pair3ContractAddress = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolContract3
    let trade1Direction = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolDirectionTrade1
    let trade2Direction = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolDirectionTrade2
    let trade3Direction = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].poolDirectionTrade3
    let startingAmount = fileJsonArrayLimit[i].startingAmount

    // Trade 1
    function anotherFunction(){
      
      let amountIn = 1000;
      
  
      if (swap1 == "WETH"){
        amountIn = 0.1;
      } else {
        amountIn = 100;
        
      }
      
      return amountIn;
  
    }
    
    console.log("Checking trade 1 acquired coin...")
    amountIn = anotherFunction();

   
    let acquiredCoinT1 = await getPrice(pair1ContractAddress, amountIn, trade1Direction)
   

    // Trade 2
    console.log("Checking trade 2 acquired coin...")
    console.log('acquiredCoinT1',acquiredCoinT1)
    if (acquiredCoinT1 == 0) {return}
    let acquiredCoinT2 = await getPrice(pair2ContractAddress, acquiredCoinT1, trade2Direction)

    // Trade 3
    console.log("Checking trade 3 acquired coin...")
    console.log('acquiredCoinT2',acquiredCoinT2)
    if (acquiredCoinT2 == 0) {return}
    let acquiredCoinT3 = await getPrice(pair3ContractAddress, acquiredCoinT2, trade3Direction)
```

As soon as one of `acquiredCoin` == 0 looping and script stop execution. How can I make the script jumping to the following row in this case ?

```
Checking trade 1 acquired coin...
Checking trade 2 acquired coin...
acquiredCoinT1 99.985968038099912576
Checking trade 3 acquired coin...
acquiredCoinT2 0
PS C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\Uniswap3JS>
```

Comment: Use `continue` to go to the next iteration of the loop, not `return`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for a noob question)